# R: error with jags

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

```
library(rjags)
library(pcnetmeta)
data(smoke)
set.seed(1234)
hom.eqcor.out <- nma.ab.bin(s.id, t.id, r, n, data = smoke,
                            param = c("AR"), model = "het_cor", prior.type = "chol", c = 10,
                            higher.better = TRUE, n.adapt = 5000, n.iter = 100000, n.chains = 2)
```

I'm using the `nma.ab.bin` function in `pcnetmet`. However, I get the following error:

"Error in update.default(jags.m, n.iter = n.burnin) : 
  need an object with call component"

I've tried playing around with the `n.adapt`, and `n.iter`. Using `n.adapt = 400` and `n.iter = 1000` has no problem. But increasing those values seems to lead to the above error?

Comment: This looks like an issue with the pcnetmeta package - have you tried contacting the developer of that package? In any case your title (error with jags) is not very descriptive of the problem.